# How can `nvarchar` fields of a table in SQLServer database be converted correctly when generating entities from tables via Eclipse JPA Tools

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

I tried to generate entities from tables in eclipse via JPA Tools (image below).

[image: eclipse jpa tools]

While converting, JPA Tools defines object types for fields whose type are `nvarchar`.

[image: generating entities]

You can see the database definition below.

[image: db definition]

How can I fix the type of `nvarchar` fields, as you can see, they should be string.

Second problem is that by default, eclipse set primitive types for fields of a table when generating entitites from tables. How can I set object types for fields, for example I want to use `Integer` type instead of `int` type.